# Laravel Mix is skipping some CSS files and not outputting everything

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I see Laravel is getting rid of Elixir with v8.0, so I'm working through changing all of our apps over to Mix.

I am able to successfully mix my `js` files into `all.js`, and the `scss` files are produced and mixed into the final `all.css` file.  My problem is that it simply will not load **some** of the css files within the `style` method.  `npm run` is successful - it outputs all files without error.  It just doesn't include some of the css files.

**I have tried:**

- Moving the `js` mix above css. -- no change
- Changing the name of the offending css files -- no change
- Reducing the offending css files down to almost nothing, just a few lines -- no change
- Copy/paste of the offending css files into a single file -- WORKS

  - But this is a non-solution; if I change the base files, I would have to copy paste each time.
  - Also seems to indicate that the problem is not with the css???

Elixir handled this perfectly and did all I need to. What am i missing with Mix??

**Webpack.js** (trimmed):

```
mix.scripts(['public/js/sweetalert1.js', 'public/js/base.js', 'public/js/jquery.tablesorter.js',
            'public/js/jquery.validate.js'], 'public/output/all.js')
            .options({
                processCssUrls: false
            }).version();  // Success

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/tablesorterColumns.scss', 'public/css/mixed'); // Success


mix.styles([ 'public/css/mixed/base.css', 'public/jquery.tablesorter.css',
           'public/css/swal1.css', 'public/css/bootstrap-dropdown-menu.css'], 'public/output/all.css').version();  
           // Fails reading two files, but Success on output of the others
```

Everything works except it simply doesn't touch the two files, `bootstrap-dropdown-menu.css` and `swal1.css`

Comment: works for me, are you on the latest version of mix?

Comment: Thanks Andy, yes, just pulled all the latest stuff in order to make the move from Elixir.  Frustrating waste of time - Elixir worked fine, and this does nothing new for us... but forced to 'upgrade'.

Comment: I have the same problem and I find that if I build to dev, it works ok, but if I build to prod, some css is missing.

Comment: Also having the same problem with Mix 6.0.49, in development it outputs all the files correctly in production some files are missing